# How to parse this json answer using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[{"ID":83,"post_author":"1","post_date":"2011-12-20 19:17:52","post_date_gmt":"2011-12-20 19:17:52","post_content":"This is my fiat project","post_title":"Fiat","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"open","ping_status":"open","post_password":"","post_name":"fiat","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2011-12-20 19:17:52","post_modified_gmt":"2011-12-20 19:17:52","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":0,"guid":"http:\/\/imiodrag.dyndns.org:8080\/other_media\/?p=83","menu_order":0,"post_type":"post","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw"}]

  $.get('http://foo.com/lol', function(data) {
   var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
     $.each(val, function(key1, val1) {
       items.push('<li id="' + key1 + '">' + val1 + '</li>');
     });

});
 $('.content').html(items.join(''));
});
```

How should I parse this?

Comment: Parse what?  Ask a real question to get a real answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse this JSON file using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668627/parse-this-json-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: $('.ss a').live('click',function() {
    $.getJSON('http://foo.com/category/default/', function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('.red').html(obj.post_content);
    });
    return false;
}); still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Native to ECMAScript 5 is `JSON.parse`.

Or you can implment it here. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js